# How can I merge two different package(.apk ) in an Android application?

Tags: android

I want to implement PDF viewer in my Android application. My application has option of reading some document and I want to open those doc in PDF by default. My application .apk is ready and I have PDF viewer apk with me. What I want is to merge these 2 apk into a single project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the code for both projects it's not really possible to merge them into a single project.  You can call the PDF Viewer from your application using Intents.