# How can I call the .apk file of PDF Viewer through intent of my application?

Tags: android

I have only .APK file of PDF Viewer and my requirement is to use pdf viewer for  reading document called through Web API . Is there any possibility to integrate these two in same package apart from source code ?

Comment: Your title and question don't quite match up. What do you mean by "reading document called through web API"? You want to open PDFs found on the web in a PDF reader application?

Answer (score 3):

Making the assumption here that you're trying to get a PDF from the web to open in your PDF reader application, you would need to include an intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

This captures PDF files that are being requested from the web — note that you would have to handle the downloading over HTTP yourself.

However, your question seems to suggest (I think) that you don't have the code — only the APK file.

If you want to open a PDF in this application, just create an `Intent` with `Action.VIEW` and the URI to the PDF file to open.

This topic, along with the inability to merge multiple APKs together without the source, has already covered in the answer to your previous question:
[How can I merge two different package(.apk ) in an android appliation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435312/how-can-i-merge-two-different-package-apk-in-an-android-appliation)